# Edit post + "New edit to this post" = Extra "navigate away" prompt

Tags: bug, editor

Instead of explaining this bug in prose form, I'll just list the steps you need to reproduce it.

1. Begin editing a post (not sure if actually making any changes makes a difference)
2. A wild *"An edit has been made to this post"* dialog appears!
3. Click on said dialog to refresh the post's content, discarding your edits and taking you out of post-edit mode
4. Edits looks okay (*surprised look on face*), so I'll just navigate away
5. **Are you sure you want to navigate away? You may lose your changes. [OK] [CANCEL]**

I can see why this hasn't been caught before; it's kind of uncommon. If you didn't catch the bug: I'm no longer making edits, therefore the "Navigate away" prompt shouldn't show up.